# Connection refused: connect Aborting action - session using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I have 50 threads test in JMeter with multiple session but when I test it half of the threads is failed and I got this error Connection:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: Connection refused: connect Aborting action - session 656255658 was closed
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have exception in server? is problem is load related? (e.g. with 10 threads didn't occurred)

Comment: I test it in 20 threads it works fine but when I test it in 50 threads half of that is failed

Comment: You now need to investigate where is the bottle neck, check application log for relevant exception

Comment: is this a server problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check 2 things:

- are you sure you’re not reusing same session accross threads ? Are you correctly correlating the session id.
- If issue only happens over some limit (not at 25 users for example, but at 50) then it’s a load issue or configuration limit on server side

Comment: im test it in 20 threads and it works fine..but when I test it in 50 threads half of that is failed